# What is the origin of the DNA sequence projected onto the Velociraptor?

Tags: jurassic-park, genetics

Towards the end of Jurassic Park, there is a scene where a nucleotide sequence is projected onto a velociraptor. I originally watched this movie in 1994, and after recently re-watching it, I'm wondering what the source of the nucleotide sequence is. I have a suspicion that it is either totally random, or something taken from a textbook.

[image: Velociraptor DNA]

The following is a transcription (in [FASTA format](https://bioinformatics.stackexchange.com/q/16091/2028), for anyone else who wants to try searching GenBank, EMBL or DDBJ for possible matches) of several lines from the above frame of the movie.

```
>velociraptor_line_8
TTATGTGTGTTAACTCTTGCCGAGATGCTAAGTAGCAAAGT
>velociraptor_line_9
GCGTAAGCCCAGAGAGATTCAATCGATCCTATTAA
>velociraptor_line_10
CTGCCAATAGCTATCTGCTACAGTATTTTACG
>velociraptor_line_11
CTATCTGTCGATCTCCGCACGTCC
>velociraptor_line_12
TAGTAAAGGGCAAATCTGA
>velociraptor_line_13
GCTCGCACTCTCTA
```

I did a [GenBank BLASTn](https://blast.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/Blast.cgi?PROGRAM=blastn&PAGE_TYPE=BlastSearch&LINK_LOC=blasthome) against one of the lines here and ended up with a 93% match to some mouse DNA, but these sequences are too short and can't be interpreted from the projection with 100% accuracy, so it is difficult to get a good basis for comparison. I was expecting a 100% match to something, so I'm hoping there is more to the story. For reference, the release date of the movie was June 9, 1993, about a year after GenBank went online at NCBI, although the original database existed since 1982 and until 1993 most DNA sequences were published in print.

Comment: Short of someone who worked on the film I doubt anyone could do more of a DNA search than what you already did. I salute your effort.